# Debugging an Excel class library add-in in VBA, created and run in Visual Studio VB .Net

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, vsto

Can someone offer any clues?

I can successfully begin debugging my Excel add-in through VS's attach process. I have chosen class library, targeting .Net framework. I can step through the code. As soon as I want to inspect a variable in the Excel model from VS, VS and Excel start getting error messages. Can you please assist me in what is wrong? I am now desperate. I believe it is in my setting it up in    VS.

I know how to create add-ins for Excel, no problem. The issue is debugging anything created for Excel from Visual Studio VB.Net. After I attach the process from VS and run the macro in VBA, I can step through the code from VS. In the watch window of VS, I have added objects from Excel, no problem. Expanding some of them creates a debugging error in both VS and VBA. Sometimes an exception is generated. Please see the picture.

**To start, here are various versions I am running:**

- Microsoft Excel for Microsoft 365 MSO (16.0.12827.20236) 64-bit, version 2005 click-to-run
- Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019:
  VisualStudio.16.Release/16.6.1+30128.74, Microsoft .NET Framework,
  Version 4.8.03752
- Windows: OS Name Microsoft Windows 10 Pro,
  Version   10.0.18363, Build 18363

**Here is the procedure. It will answer the questions of options that I have selected**

1. Visual Studio (run as administrator):

   1. Project created "Class Library (.NET Framework)", Visual Basic. Framework: .NET 4.8
   2. Ribbon -> Any CPU -> x64
   3. Add reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions -> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel (15.0.0.0)
   4. Project -> classlibrary1 properties

      - Application -> Assembly information -> ☒ Make assembly COM-Visible
      - Compile -> ☒ Register for COM interop
      - Compile -> Advanced Compiler Options -> ☐ Enable optimizations
      - Compile -> Advanced Compiler Options -> Generate debug info: Full
      - Compile -> Advanced Compiler Options -> ☒ Define DEBUG constant
      - Debug -> ☒ Enable native code debugging
   5. Tools -> Options

      - Debugging -> General -> ☒ Enable Just My Code
      - Debugging -> General -> Use Managed Compatibility mode
      - Debugging -> Symbol -> ☒ C:\Users\jfwei_000\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\bin\x64\Debug\ClassLibrary1.pdb
      - Debugging -> Symbol -> cache symbols in this directory: C:\Users\jfwei_000\source\jCacheSymbols
   6. Class1.vb

      ```vb
      Public Class Class1
          Public Function xWakeMeUp(VBA_App_Obj As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application) As String
              Dim xWb As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook
              Dim xWSheet As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet
              xWb = VBA_App_Obj.ActiveWorkbook
              Stop
              xWSheet = xWb.Sheets("sheet1")
              xWakeMeUp = "test"
          End Function
      End Class
      ```
   7. Build

      - Clean solution
      - Build solution
      - Results: Rebuild All: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped
   8. Save everything
2. Excel:

   1. Developer -> Visual Basic
   2. Tools -> References -> browse -> C:\Users\jfwei_000\source\repos\ClassLibrary1\bin\x64\Debug\ClassLibrary1.tlb
   3. Insert -> Module

      ```vb
      Option Explicit

      Dim xMyAddin As New Class1

      Sub LetsDoIt()
          Dim xRet As String
          Dim xObj As Excel.Application
          Set xObj = Excel.Application
          xRet = xMyAddin.xWakeMeUp(xObj)
          Stop
      End Sub
      ```
   4. Save
3. Visual Studio:

   1. Debug -> Attach to process -> find excel.exe in list -> Attach
4. Excel:

   1. Position cursor on `xRet = xMyAddin.xWakeMeUp(xObj)`
   2. Run -> Run Sub / Userform

Here is the picture in Visual Studio
It should be noted that when I select continue in VS, it proceeds as normal. Back in VBA, the return value is "test".

[image: picture in Visual Studio]

Comment: You should really add some information on the exceptions that you are encountering.  As it stands, we have no specific question to answer,  That said, I recommend that you launch Excel from VS directly (Project Menu->Proj Name Properties->Debug Tab->Start External Program (you can also specify a workbook to open in the "Command Line Arguments"). Then you can press F5 to start debugging. Also, set all Project COM references to be "Copy Local" instead of "Embed Interop Types=True"; this will ensure that all needed interfaces are accessible during debug.

Comment: Have you added related reference in your project and received any error? From you describe, I can't figure out the specified result you want to know.